# Shift only placeholder text to up when user type writing in a input field text-box

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a signup form in which i have some input fields with placeholder text. I dont have any label for input field as i have placeholder. I want to shift placeholder text to up when user types writing.. What should i add to my css file to make it happen.

below image shows my signup form

[image: signup form]

my signup.php file:

```
<div class="loginForm">

        <form action="signUp.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off" required>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" autocomplete="off" required>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required>

          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
          <input type="email" name="email2" placeholder="Confirm email" autocomplete="off" required>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
          <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm password" autocomplete="off" required>

          <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>

      </div>
```

my css file that i have tried:

```
.signInContainer .column form input[type="text"],
.signInContainer .column form input[type="email"],
.signInContainer .column form input[type="password"] {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .8s;
}

.signInContainer .column form input[type="text"]:focus,
.signInContainer .column form input[type="email"]:focus,
.signInContainer .column form input[type="password"]:focus {

  outline: none;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #464646;
}
```

Comment: I am almost certain this isn't possible without javascript. Are you ok with using javascript?

Comment: yes i dont have problem

Comment: Just added a solution with pure HTML+CSS (not bragging, just calling attention to a possible solution)

Comment: It can be done using only CSS but we have changed a little bit structure like move placeholder to a label. Are you ok with the changes? Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui can't see the file you have changed

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution:** You'll need a `label` for that and a little bit of markup and a webkit browser.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-text {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}


/* the second part of the trick is that you place your label to
look like a placeholder */

label.move-out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 15px;
  color: lightgrey;
  transition: top 0.4s, left 0.4s
}


/* :placeholder-shown now works with an "empty" placeholder and a
correctly positioned label, and also keeps the label at position,
when data is in the input field */


/* :-webkit-autofill is there if Chrome wants to fill your input
box automatically */

input:focus+label.move-out,
input:not( :placeholder-shown)+label.move-out,
input:-webkit-autofill+label.move-out {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: top 0.4s, left 0.4s;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- the first part of the trick is that you create an "empty"
  placeholder attr -->
  <input id="i1" class="input-text" type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <label class="move-out" for="i1">Label 1</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- the first part of the trick is that you create an "empty"
  placeholder attr -->
  <input id="i2" class="input-text" type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <label class="move-out" for="i2">Label 2</label>
</div>
```

**It's important to place the `label` AFTER the input field**, as CSS has a selector to select element after an other element (`element + element`), but there's no selector to select an element before an other.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an empty label (which wouldn't show in the rendered output since it's empty) and when you type **anything** in the input, change the value of the label to the placeholder of your input.

```js
document.getElementById("input_text").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_text").placeholder;
});
```

```html
<label id="text"></label>
<input type="text" id="input_text" placeholder="Type here" />
```